# warning before delete a row of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

This is the code I have try to create but it doesn't work, it show's first the print line and then creates the 'alert', if I choose yes, iit will delete the row of the next time I click Delete.

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        crearAlertaDoble(titulo: "¿Seguro que deseas eliminar este calendario?", mensaje: "")
        print("opcion elegida: \(opcionAlertaMensaje)")
        if (opcionAlertaMensaje == 1) {
            objetoContenedor.calendarios.remove(at: indexPath.row) //WIP, MOSTRAR MENSAJE SI ESTA SEGURO
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            opcionAlertaMensaje = 2
        } else {

        }

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

And this is the alert code:

```
func crearAlertaDoble(titulo: String, mensaje: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let botonUno = UIAlertAction(title: "NO!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.opcionAlertaMensaje = 0
    } )
    let botonDos = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        self.opcionAlertaMensaje = 1
    } )

    alert.addAction(botonDos)
    alert.addAction(botonUno)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because UIAlertAction does removing in closure handler. It's asynchronous. In your code first run all code of commitEditing() method, including removing. And only after user tap on Si, or No - handler fires. But it do nothing, because there's nothing about deleting in handlers.

You can fix it like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title:  "¿Seguro que deseas eliminar este calendario?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let botonUno = UIAlertAction(title: "NO!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.opcionAlertaMensaje = 0
        } )
        let botonDos = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
            self.objetoContenedor.calendarios.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        } )

        alert.addAction(botonDos)
        alert.addAction(botonUno)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

In that case you don't need to store chosen option, but if you need to store it - you can add it (in handlers also)

Answer (score 3):

The method to display the alert controller works asynchronously. You cannot process the result synchronously right after calling the method.

There are several solutions, one of them is to add a completion handler:

```
func crearAlertaDoble(titulo: String, mensaje: String, completion:@escaping (Int) ->()) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titulo, message: mensaje, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let botonUno = UIAlertAction(title: "NO!", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
        completion(0)
    } )
    let botonDos = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: .default, handler: { action in
        completion(1)
    } )

    alert.addAction(botonDos)
    alert.addAction(botonUno)

    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And use it in `tableView:commit:forRowAt:`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        crearAlertaDoble(titulo: "¿Seguro que deseas eliminar este calendario?", mensaje: "") { result in
            print("opcion elegida: \(result)")
            if result == 1 {
                self.objetoContenedor.calendarios.remove(at: indexPath.row) //WIP, MOSTRAR MENSAJE SI ESTA SEGURO
                self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            } else {

            }
        }

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this with the other comment it work :D